# Foreign key is null despite being populated properly in database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following entities in my context:

```
   public class Asset
    {
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        public Registration Registration { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Asset Type")]
        public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(Constants.SerialNumberStart, Constants.SerialNumberEnd)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d8}")]
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(Constants.EquipNumberStart, Constants.EquipNumberEnd)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d12}")]
        public long EquipNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Profile")]
        [Range(Constants.ProfileStart, Constants.ProfileEnd)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d2}")]
        public int Profile { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetType
    {
        public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
        public List<Asset> Asset { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Asset Type")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string AssetTypeFullName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Asset Alias")]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string AssetTypeShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

I've seeded my database and everything looks fine, the AssetType foreign key properly shows the index into my AssetType table data.

But when I try to get the data ready for the View in the code below, the AssetType key/data is null.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Logger.Debug("Index");
        RegistrationServerContext dbNotLazy = new RegistrationServerContext();
        return View(dbNotLazy.Assets.ToList());
    }
```

When I set a break point and examine my dbNotLazy.Asset data, the AssetType foreign key is null.

I thought this might have to do with Lazy Loading, but as you can see, I create a new context before my View call. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: do you need to use .Include("AssetType") in your query? AssetType property will never be lazy loaded since it is not virtual. Therefore when you get your Assets the navigation property is never expanded. If you use .Include it should expand your navigation property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use an [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) - change

```
return View(dbNotLazy.Assets.ToList());
```

to

```
return View(dbNotLazy.Assets.Include("AssetType").ToList());
```

Lazy loading doesn't always seem to work immediately.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment lazy loading will never work in this case since the navigation property is not virtual.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, I'm not sure why I couldn't select your answer as the solution. But now that I've read more on the issue, I understand your comment on virtual better. Anyway, my code works now - so I appreciate both of the responses.